# JQuery Mobile Mysql Database Filter System

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I am looking to make a filtering system to my database records.
I can make records load, but I am looking to filter the records with multiple keywords using a JQuery Mobile dropdown bar. However I do not know how to put this all together into one thing.

Here is the code for the JQuery Mobile dropdown options:

```
        <label for="select-h-6a">Genre</label>
        <select name="select-h-6a" id="select-h-6a">
            <option value="#">Rock</option>
            <option value="#">Pop</option>
            <option value="#">Dance</option>
        </select>
        <label for="select-h-6b">Role</label>
        <select name="select-h-6b" id="select-h-6b">
            <option value="#">Singer</option>
            <option value="#">Drummer</option>
            <option value="#">Guitar</option>
        </select>
        <label for="select-h-6c">Members</label>
        <select name="select-h-6c" id="select-h-6c">
            <option value="#">1</option>
            <option value="#">2</option>
            <option value="#">3</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is my code at the moment with post title and post content on it, I can add in more to post but at the moment it in only those who options:

```
 $posts = getAllPosts();

<div id="searchpost">
      <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
       <div id="postTitle">

        <?php echo $posts[$p]["post_title"];?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
         <div id="postContent">
        <?php echo $posts[$p]["post_content"];}?></div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

and the functions:

```
function getAllPosts() {
    require "config.php";
    $posts = $c->query ( "SELECT * FROM posts" );

    if ( $posts->num_rows > 0 ) {

        while( $row = $posts->fetch_assoc() )  {

                $postData[] = array( "user_id" => $row[ "user_id" ], "post_title" => $row[ "post_title" ], "post_content" => $row[ "post_content" ] );
            }
    } else {
        return "No Data";
    }
    return $postData;
}
```

However as you can see, it calls for things in the database specifically. How can I make what I select in the drop down menus be shown instead of the specifics.

Can this be added for multiple selected options such as selecting rock, singer and 2 members showing only the records that all three of those in. I assume if I don't want something specific in option 2 I can have an all option which searches for everything in that category.

So, I need help with:
- Writing code that will search my database records and show all that address all of the options chosen in the JQuery Mobile drop down bars.

I hope you understand what I am needing help with.

**Edit:**

My database:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0W9.png)

Connection: (config.php)

```
<?php

    $c = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "user", "pass", "database");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {

        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming this question is about how to build an SQL query based on submitted form data. It might be more secure (and generally easier) if you use the PHP PDO-extension instead. php.net will help you there.

Your query, after moving to PDO (strongly recommended) will look roughly like this.

```
$sql = ‘select * from posts 
    where genre=:genre
    and role=:role
    and members=:members’;

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(
    array(‘:genre’ => $_GET[‘genre’],
          ‘:role’ => $_GET[‘role’],
          ‘:members’=> $_GET[‘members’])
    );
$result = $sth->fetchAll(); // this should be enough to echo a result
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, do I use this instead of both the second and third pieces of code I put? :)

Comment: Within the getAllPosts function, but if you put exactly that, it will fail. What I pasted was really a rough guide only - not understanding anything about your database schema. (this is likely why you have no answers - the question is impossible to answer correctly)

Comment: I've added my database and config, would this help?